# What is the solution GPU driver issu?

Tags: android-studio

What is the actual solution for GPU driver issue? I can not run AVD!. only device shows but android not start. I am looking that solution for Last 7 days . If I change graphics card, will it work? What is the effective solution??

Comment: I have changed graphics option to software but didn’t work, i have   tried to run avd from terminal, run from genymotion but I have not success. All time I got the same message.

Answer (score 0):

NO, you do not need to change the graphics card. You just do one thing that makes sure the AVD Drivers are up-to-date. Or you can update it. After that, the android studio can run and your code will render it properly and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first.

1. `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.`

If that didn't work. Try the following.

2. `Close the android Studio, killall -9 java to ensure all java process has been terminated. And relaunch Android Studio.`

And update the Drivers. Then it will work fine.